# JQuery load() status is not making sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have the following code:

```
$("#wifi").load("myurl .learn-press-course-results-progress", function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            $('#wifi_header').show();
            console.log("wifi");
        };
});
```

Which basically is trying to fetch a students progress in a given learnpress course, and, in case there is any progress (i.e in case the student is enrolled in the course), it displays the course header (and it's progress) in their dashboard so that they can easily continue their course, like so:

[image: Student dashboard, working]

However, and the reason for the `status` conditional, if the student is not enrolled, then the div `.learn-press-course-results-progress` does not exist, and therefore I do not wish to display the course heading (i.e, I want "nothing" to happen".)

Problem is, even with the success conditional, this happens:

[image: Student progress, not correctly displaying]

Now what's interesting is that I nested that `console.log("class")` in order to see what was going on, and it turns out that in every instance, including those where the load fails and therefore it shouldn't display the header, I get the class log in my console.

So, my question is, how can I fix this? Is this something that has to do with the status?

Edit: prior to this code block, I have done `$("#class_header").hide();` which is why I'm running `show()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Not finding a selector via jQuery is generally not considered any kind of error.

Comment: The thing is that per the jquery documentation, in case the selector is not ofund the AJAX request exists with an error.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere in the `.load()` documentation (the section "Loading page fragments").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of `container`. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of `result`, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

> jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

If you call:

```
$("#wifi").load("myurl .learn-press-course-results-progress");
```

If the the page loads, and none of the elements have the `.learn-press-course-results-progress`, `wifi` will be populated with null data or "". The status will still be 200 or `success`, as `myurl` exists and can be called, yet the content you are seeking is just missing.

This is why your `$("#wifi")` is empty and why your conditional statement is triggered.

Consider the following.

```
$("#wifi").load("myurl .learn-press-course-results-progress", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if ($("#wifi").children().length && status == "success") {
    $('#wifi_header').show();
    console.log("wifi");
  };
});
```

This checks to see if `wifi` has any elements within in. If the Data brought back is only Text, then check the Text Length.

```
if($("#wifi").text().trim() != "" ...){}
```

One of these should help you.

Comment: Dude nailed it. I used the children().length argument to find those that had a length of 0 (after loading, if it is successful) and hide them. Thank you soooo much!